# Unexpected function expression. (prefer-arrow-callback)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am receiving three errors in the below code with `eslint`, whilst the function appears to be working as intended in the application.

Errors:

```
[eslint] Unexpected unnamed function. (func-names)
[eslint] Unexpected function expression. (prefer-arrow-callback)
[eslint] Do not access Object.prototype method 'hasOwnProperty' from target object. (no-prototype-builtins)
```

Code:

```
const getCount = campaignData.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  if (!acc.hasOwnProperty(curr.status)) {
    acc[curr.status] = 1
  } else {
    acc[curr.status] += 1
  }
  return acc;    
}, {});
```

I am using within the `render` of a ReactJS component for use as `{getCount.active}`.

As it is working, should I ignore it?

Comment: You *can* ignore it. But you *should not* ignore linting errors. It helps to improve your quality and makes sure that you follow certain standards.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thats what the linter means:

> [eslint] Unexpected unnamed function. (func-names)

Giving proper names to functions makes error stacks more readable, `error at accumulate` is way more expressive then `error at anonymous` so it recommends you to change:

```
 function(acc, curr)
```

To

```
 function accumulate(acc, curr)
```

Alternatively you can follow this advice:

> [eslint] Unexpected function expression. (prefer-arrow-callback)

If you don't need `this` inside a function you could use the arrow functions syntax instead, its a bit shorter.

```
 function(acc, curr) {
```

becomes

```
 (acc, curr) => {
```

> [eslint] Do not access Object.prototype method 'hasOwnProperty' from target object. (no-prototype-builtins)

Inherited classes might override that by accident, so it recommends you to use:

```
 curr.status in acc
```

But all those hints are actually just some improvements of readability, there is no functional difference.

> As it is working, should I ignore it?

If you think that "code is good if it is working" then yes, otherwise not.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed response. I'll accept it as it allows. I have OCD to the red squiggles and would generally fix a lint error. However this one I cannot make good with Lint whilst not producing additional errors and breaking the code. Even taking your suggestions I end up with more wrong than right.

Comment: @darren then do it like in this case. Read the hints and read / ask what they are about so that you get a better coding style in the longterm :) oh, and I'm glad to help

Comment: Yes I agree. I ended up changing much of it around using your notes and it worked a dream. `const getCount = campaignData.reduce((acc, cur) => {
      if (!acc[cur.status]) {
        acc[cur.status] = [];
      }
      acc[cur.status].push(cur);
      return acc;
    }, {});` did the trick. Thanks again.